# Alarm auto call when start device in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My program implement AlarmManager. Now Time is 10:00 and I set alarm 10:05. At 10:02 I power off device, after that at 10:06 I start my device again, when my device is started, onReceive() function of BroadcastReceiver auto call and alarm auto call. I want to disable this alarm, how to do this?

Thanks in advanced :)